# Ajax doesn't get HTML data from render_to_response

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm very confused with my code. Here is the ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search-filter").click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            q=$('#q').val();
            q_fields=$('#q-fields').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                data: {'q': q, 'q_fields': q_fields},
                success: function(data) {
                    var returned_html = $(data);
                    alert(returned_html);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

My view returns a HTML that I can print. It's as expected.

```
if self.request.is_ajax():
    return render_to_response(self.obj_template, {'object_list': res}, context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))
```

I can't get the return in my var returned_html. I should have miss something. But what? The response from firebug is object of type 'HttpResponse' has no len().

EDIT:

Here is the template: self.obj_template I use to build my piece of HTML.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <li>object.name</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And the print the return of my view I'd like to retrieve:

```
print render_to_response(self.obj_template, {'object_list': res}, context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))


<tr class="clickableRow" href="/contacts/1054/">
    <td>ABBA</td>
    <td>toto</td>
    <td>auie@auienrtsi.fr</td>
    <td>CAM SA</td>
</tr>

<tr class="clickableRow" href="/contacts/1045/">
    <td>toto</td>
    <td>toto</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>None</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the type/value of `res`?

Comment: @OozeMeister it's a queryset as object.objects.all()

Comment: When you `print` the `render_to_response` what does the console show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave too few information on this topic to be helped and I'm sorry about that. My error consisted in the use of a CBV to respond a formated HTML without considering that the CBV render a whole page. So I had to call a function outside the CBV to return the exact code as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's your `js` that was wrong, how about try this:

```
var returned_html = data;
```

Comment: THanks, you were right on that error. But my problem came from the use of a class base view to return a piece of HTML, which is not what a CBS is for.